# Why is my Powershell WPF data binding pulling System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Test 1 instead of Test 1

Tags: wpf, powershell

I'm learning how to use Powershell to create WPF forms. I have a ComboBox full of items, and when selected, they should populate a TextBox. I used a data binding to connect the Text property of the TextBox to the currently selected ComboBox item. But when I select an item, it populates as
`System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Test 1` instead of just `Test 1`.

[Example Program Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUtgY.png)

```
[xml]$Form = @"
<Window 

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    Title="Test Window" Height="200" Width="400">

    <StackPanel>

        <ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" Margin="10"> 
            <ComboBoxItem>Test 1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Test 2</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>

        <TextBox Name="textBox" Margin="10" Text="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox1, Path=SelectedValue}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>

"@


$NR=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Form)
$WIN=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $NR )

$WIN.Showdialog()
```

I've seen some other ways to do this in C#, but I'm trying to do this as just a Powershell script.

Comment: While i know the technial reason for the observed problem, i am puzzled by what you wanto to use the textbox for. If you edit the text in the textbox, what do you expect/want to happen?

Comment: I plan to use the program to run sql queries; so the dropdown will contain some premade queries and they can be fine-tuned in the textbox before being run.

Comment: Ah, okay. So you want to actually change the content of those items. Answer incoming...

Comment: On a second thought, do you really want to change the ComboBoxItems themselves? Wouldn't it make more sense to just have an editable combobox (which would leave the ComboBoxItems themselves untouched/unchanged)?

Comment: Actually yea that would probably work even better. How would I set that?

Comment: Just set the ComboBox to `IsEditable="True"`. (By the way, even if your goal is a Powershell Script, try to write the XAML stuff in Visual Studio if possible, and afterwards copy&paste the XAML into your PS script. IntelliSense/auto completion in Visual Studio makes writing XAML so much easier...)

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is probably to just make the ComboBox editable and discard the TextBox-based approach:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" Margin="10" IsEditable="True"> 
    ...
```

This allows users to not only choose text (ComboBoxItems) from the drop-down, but also allows them to enter and modify the current text while the ComboBoxItems themselves remain untouched/unchanged.

However, if it is indeed desired to change the text of the ComboBoxItems themselves through a TextBox, you would need to bind against the `Content` property of the ComboBoxItem. Like so:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox" Margin="10" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=ComboBox1}"/>
```

After editing the text in the textbox, the item in the ComboBox will change accordingly (when the textbox loses focus).

If you want the ComboBoxItem to follow the edits in the textbox in "real-time", change the binding to:

```
Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=ComboBox1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```